# When do we need to call std::string::capacity()?

Tags: c++, string, stl, use-case, capacity

As a user, I have std::string's size()/resize()/reserve() to know and manage the memory of all these strings.

But, when do I have to use capacity()? Is there any use case or necessity that I should call this function to do something to achieve something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good question. I'm going to run a risk of a flame war by saying that the calling of `capacity()` in user code is a code smell.

The only reason to call it would be to avoid a memory allocation mid-operation. In which case, a cleaner and more fault-tolerant strategy would be to create one's own class (say `limited_length_string`). A possible implementation might allocate sufficient memory up front (either through it's own implementation or by encapsulating a `std::string` and calling `reserve()` on it.

If you see this call in code you're working on, then beware of landmines. If you write this call, it's a signal that your design is suspect.

Answer (score 3):

If you for some reason want to avoid to allocated memory. For example in a very performance critical section of a real time application.

Answer (score 1):

capacity tells you the maximum numbers of chars that you current string can store without growing in size. So you'll use it if you don't want your string to grow in size and take up more memory.